# Where do the "virtual/..." terms come from?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In Bitbake I can build e.g. the Linux Kernel with `bitbake virtual/kernel` or U-Boot with `bitbake virtual/bootloader`.

Where do those "virtual/..." terms come from?

I used `find` for patters such as "virtual/kernel" in the poky directory, but there are nearly infinite results and I don't know where to search.

Can I e.g. direct `virtual/bootloader` to a custom recipe when I might have programmed an own bootloader?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From bitbake user-manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html)

> As an example of adding an extra provider, suppose a recipe named
>   foo_1.0.bb contained the following:
>
> `PROVIDES += "virtual/bar_1.0"`
>
> The recipe now provides both "foo_1.0" and "virtual/bar_1.0". The "virtual/" namespace is often used to denote
>   cases where multiple providers are expected with the user choosing
>   between them. Kernels and toolchain components are common cases of
>   this in OpenEmbedded.
>
> Sometimes a target might have multiple providers. A common example is
>   "virtual/kernel", which is provided by each kernel recipe. Each
>   machine often selects the best kernel provider by using a line similar
>   to the following in the machine configuration file:
>
> `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto"`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `your meta-layer/conf/machine/here` you can find macros.
   `your-meta-layer/recipes-bsp/barebox(or U-boot)`  here you can find `bootloader` recipes(.bb).